# How to stop alert box to display when back button is pressed in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

My PHP code works properly but the problem is, when I press the back button, the alert dialog again shows up. The alert dialog is needed while logging in, and it works properly. But when I press the back button, it again shows the alert box.

```
<?php

if($_POST){
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root"; 
    $pass = "";
    $db = "erp";

    $userId = $_POST['myusername'];
    $password = $_POST['mypassword'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    $query = "SELECT * from user where user_id='$userId'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($row["user_id"]==$userId){
            if($row["password"]==$password){     //when user_id and password 
                                                 //match, go to check 
                                                   //usertype
                switch($row["user_type_id"]){
                    case 1: session_start();
                            $_SESSION['erp']='true';
                            header('location:acc_setting.php');
                            break;
                    case 2: session_start();
                            $_SESSION['erp']='true';
                            header('location:dashboard.php');
                            break;
                    case 3: session_start();
                            $_SESSION['erp']='true';
                            header('location:c_course.php');
                            break; 
                }
            }
            else{
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Invalid Password")';
                echo '</script>';
            }
        }
        else{
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Invalid Username")';
                echo '</script>';
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have more worrying issues to deal with than the alert - it would appear that you are storing plain text passwords in your db!! In addition the above is vulnerable to SQL injection. To avoid the issue you are facing, rather than immediately call javascript, set a session variable and redirect back to the same page, then test for that session and then invoke the javascript

Comment: One other thing: it would be better to simply let the user know that either the username or password is wrong rather than specifically one or the other as it potentially leaks information about valid users

Comment: Thanks, but how do I set a session var and redirect it to same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the security issues I mentioned in comments and to specifically answer your subsequent question `how do I set a session var and redirect it to same page` perhaps the following might help. I simplified in a couple of places but essentially the same for the most part.

```
<?php
    if( $_POST ){

        session_start();

        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root'; 
        $pass = '';
        $db = 'erp';
        $conn = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $db );



        $destinations=array(
            1   =>  'acc_setting.php',
            2   =>  'dashboard.php',
            3   =>  'c_course.php'
        );



        $userId = $_POST['myusername'];
        $password = $_POST['mypassword'];


        /*
            This should be a prepared statement
            ->  $sql='select `password` from `users` where `user_id`=?';
            ->  $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            ->  $stmt->bind_param('s',$userid );
            etc etc

            The passwords should be hashed in the db using password_hash
            and verified in PHP using password_verify

            NEVER store plain text passwords
        */

        $query = "SELECT * from user where user_id='$userId'";


        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if( $row['user_id']==$userId ){
                /*
                    this should be password_verify 
                */
                if( $row['password']==$password ){

                    $_SESSION['erp']='true';

                    exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: %s', $destinations[ $row['user_type_id'] ] ) ) );

                } else{
                    $_SESSION['error']='Invalid Password';
                }
            } else{
                $_SESSION['error']='Invalid Username';
            }

            /*
                An error must have occurred, redirect back to oiginal page
            */
            exit( header( sprintf('Location: %s', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ) ) );
    }
?>
```

Then, in the original page where the form is

```
<form>
    <!--
        various form elements
    -->
    <?php
        if( !empty( $_SESSION['error'] ) ){
            echo $_SESSION['error'];
            unset( $_SESSION['error'] );
        }
    ?>
</form>
```